# Error while uploading (img+json) pairs on to Solana Devnet

Tags: smartcontracts, solana, nft, metaplex, candy-machine

I'm trying to upload NFT assets using the Solana devnet with candy machine v2

This is the command that I am running

```
ts-node ~/metaplex-foundation/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-v2-cli.ts upload -e devnet -k ~/.config/solana/devnet.json -cp config.json ./assets
```

when I run the command above, I get this error message:

```
Beginning the upload for 7 (img+json) pairs
started at: 1644272598092
initializing candy machine
Error deploying config to Solana network. RangeError: indeterminate span
    at Structure.getSpan (/Users/dlku/metaplex-foundation/metaplex/js/node_modules/buffer-layout/lib/Layout.js:1221:13)
    at Structure.encode (/Users/dlku/metaplex-foundation/metaplex/js/node_modules/buffer-layout/lib/Layout.js:1267:23)
    at InstructionCoder._encode (/Users/dlku/metaplex-foundation/metaplex/js/packages/cli/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/coder/instruction.ts:85:24)
```

Has anyone else ran into this issue ? Any help would be appreciated

Here's an example of the json data:

```
{
    "name":"NFT NAME",  
    "symbol": "NN",
    "description": "My collection",
    "image": "7.png",
    "properties": {
        "creators": [{"address": "00x00x00x00x000x00x00x", "share": 100}],
        "files": [{"uri": "7.png", "type": "image/png"}]
    }
}
```

and this is the config:

```
{
    "price": 0.50,
    "number": 10,
    "solTreasuryAccount":
"00x00x000x0x000x00x00x000x0000x00x00",
    "storage": "arweave"
}
```

similar questions but didn't solve my issue:

- [4 months ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69670383/problem-with-my-terminal-and-looping-error)
- [1 month ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69784046/unable-to-deploy-config-to-solana-network)
- [github](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex/issues/699)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently many users are having [issue with devnet](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex/issues/1908)

So as of March 7 2022 devnet is acting up , it'd recommend using an RPC

Comment: Yeh, devnet itself is not down, but uploading/creating a candy machine at this time is difficult to impossible. Probably because it is an intense cmd and the network is struggling.